# Magento2 - Email Marketing Question

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules, rules, catalog-rules, magento2email

We are launching a new e-commerce store soon. When a customer placed an order for first time then we want to give a unique coupon code to customer.

In Magento we have option for cart rules and catalog rules but not for customer or sales related options.

Any one suggest me how can I do this marketing?

Comment: I think this extension is works for you. https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-2-extensions/follow-up-email

Comment: you can check this MageAnts [follow up email](https://www.mageants.com/follow-up-email-for-magento-2.html) extension it will work

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a module like this. Please check below link mate

https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-2-extensions/coupon-code-generator

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/174013)

Comment: It is a module. He has to purchase that to use it. No way to add all codes here of that dude.

Comment: add some content/hint related to module, otherwise, you can add a link by commenting, no need to create an answer

Comment: ok thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create customer segment to identify the customers who placed their first order and assign that segment in cart price rules with auto generated coupons. This way, you can control the customer who is opting for the discount.

Again, you have to manually email the coupon to customer who placed their first order.

Answer (score -1):

I can recommend our free email marketing module for Magneto - https://marketplace.magento.com/sendernet-synergia-sendercommerce.html

Sender offers free plan up to 2500 subscribers and 15000 emails/month. It will be enough resources to send coupon code. Sender also have function to send abandoned cart email.

Here's you can read more information about Sender plugin features - https://www.sender.net/

Comment: I need it for magento2 but this one is magento1.x